# ways to limit disk IO utilization to raid array partition

Tags: linux, raid, performance, hp-smart-array

I have a raid array partition that is under heavy load by an nfs server, recently it has failed a quite a few times and needed intervention while at 100% utilization.

While I am determining the cause of the underlying problem, I would like to apply a limit to the utilization somehow and bottleneck the system at some other point that the disk IO.

server is debian lenny, disk is formatted with xfs, hardware is HP proliant

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ionice to set the IO class priority for the process if you are using the CFQ disk scheduler.

man ionice of course for all the details.

nfs server is in kernel though, so how you would go about limiting the kernel's IO if that is indeed where the problem is occurring you are pretty much stuck.

Good luck finding the root cause :)